# Working with for each: at the end of the loop the result is not recorded

Tags: vba, foreach

I'm stuck for about an hour with this: It looks like I've missed something.

I've written the code above to manipulate text in an array. What it's designed to do, is to get rid of ignored keywords from keywordToProcess which is what the line `j = ""` meant to do. At that line `j = ""`, `j` does turn blank, but the finished product `i = join(i," ")` still have the word that was supposed to turn blank in it. Why is it? I'm not familiar with `For Each`-loop, maybe I've missed something important.

```
For Each i In keywordToProcess
    i = Split(i, " ")
    For Each j In i
        j = RemovePrurals(j)
    Next j
        For Each j In i
            For Each k In ignoreArr
                If j = k Then
                    j = ""
                End If
            Next k
        Next j
    i = Join(i, " ")
Next i
```

Comment: You do never store your result (`j = ""`) in `i`.

Comment: How exactly do i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You use `For Each ... Next` correctly. The thing is that you are confusing variables. (I suppose keywordtoprocess is a string array.) Then `i` in `For Each` is a `Single String`. In the next line `i` changes type to `String Array` with `Split`. Then in the last line you make a `Single String` from a `String Array i` with the `Join`. But in the next step you overwrite `i` with the `Next ... For Each` where you assign the next `Single String` value to `i`. VBA lets you do this but you should avoid it. So I advice: use `Option Explicit`, declare your variables, and design before coding. Remember that there are physical memory cells behind each variables.

EDIT: I would code it this way (supposing keywordtoprocess is a string array)

```
' Dim keywordtoprocess() As Variant
Dim sKW As String      ' keyword
Dim asBuf() As Variant ' string buffer for current keyword split to pieces
Dim sK As String       ' for keywords to be ignored
Dim i As Long          ' loop

    For Each sKW In keywordtoprocess
        asBuf = Split(sKW, " ")
        For i = LBound(asBuf) To UBound(asBuf)
            asBuf(i) = RemovePrurals(asBuf(i)) ' this is the way to change value
            For Each sK In ignoreArr
                If asBuf(i) = sK Then
                    asBuf(i) = vbNullString
                End If
            Next sK
        Next i
    Next sKW
    sK = Join(asBuf, " ")
    Debug.Print sK
```

Please note that changing the loop variable does not change the real data. See my suggestion at RemovePrurals. Anyhow, you'd better avoid changing loop variable, even if you can.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Can you please explain a little more on how i at the second last line is different to in the second line?